# Como setar um caminho (FTP) para upload automatico no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Preciso de um Upload de forma automática  no código abaixo para enviar ao servidor via FTP usando Delphi, é possível?

```
var
ms: TMemoryStream;


begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then

ms := TMemoryStream.Create;



 idftp1.host := '' // Endereço do servidor FTP

 idftp1.port := ''; //Porta do servidor FTP

 idftp1.username := ''; // Parametro nome usuario servidor FTP

 idftp1.password := ''; // Parametro senha servidor FTP

 idftp1.Connect();



(Aqui Preciso mudar)

 idftp1.Put(OpenDialog1.FileName, '/projeto_ftp/' + ExtractFileName(OpenDialog1.FileName));

IdFTP1.Disconnect;



end;
```

Answer (score 0):

> idftp1.host := '' // Endereço do servidor FTP
>
> idftp1.port := ''; //Porta do servidor FTP
>
> idftp1.username := ''; // Parametro nome usuario servidor FTP
>
> idftp1.password := ''; // Parametro senha servidor FTP
>
> idftp1.Connect();
>
> (Aqui Preciso mudar)
>
> idftp1.Put(OpenDialog1.FileName, '/projeto_ftp/' +
>   ExtractFileName(OpenDialog1.FileName));
>
> IdFTP1.Disconnect;

Tente assim...

```
 idftp1.host := '' // Endereço do servidor FTP
 idftp1.port := ''; //Porta do servidor FTP
 idftp1.username := ''; // Parametro nome usuario servidor FTP
 idftp1.password := ''; // Parametro senha servidor FTP
  try
    idftp1.Connect(true, -1);
  except
    idftp1.Passive := True;
    idftp1.Connect;
  end;
idftp1.ChangeDir('/var/www/html'); //SEU DIRETORIO

//CAMINHO COMPLETO DO LOCAL QUE O ARQUIVO ESTA EM SUA MAQUINA
idftp1.Put('C:\Arquivo.txt', 'Arquivo.txt', false);
IdFTP1.Disconnect;
```